Как из ансибла сделать проверку вхождения хоста в список?
Есть файл с переменными списками vars вот такой формы
zabbix:
  mon1:
    host: http://server1/api_jsonrpc.php
    groups:
      - Name1
      - Name2
      - Name3
  mon2:
    host: http://server1/api_jsonrpc.php
    groups:
      - Name4
      - Name5
      - Name6

как из плейбука проверить входит ли хост в какую то группу ? и в зависимости от того куда он входит присвоить переменную c адресом хоста мониторинга
